# AWS - Cannot create ElastiCache-CacheCluster - 'CacheSecurityGroup not found error'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticache

I have a cloud formation script shown below, I hope to create a Security Group and Elasti Cache. However I get an error shown below
  **CREATE_FAILED
  AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
  CacheSecurityGroup not found: elasticacheta....**

I use cloudformation routinely but never with the cache. I do not want to use a VPC in my scenario and have gone through the documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html and related links but with no luck - help appreciated.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  ElasticacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: "Access from webservers only"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        FromPort: '11211'
        ToPort: '11211'
  ElasticacheCluster:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster"
    DependsOn: ElasticacheSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: "true"
      Engine: "memcached"
      CacheNodeType: "cache.t1.micro"
      NumCacheNodes: "1"
      CacheSecurityGroupNames:
      - Ref: ElasticacheSecurityGroup
```

Comment: Try using `AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroup` instead of `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup` for non-VPC configurations.

Comment: That helped - It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Echoing [jordanm](https://serverfault.com/users/105633/jordanm)'s comment, change the resource type to [**`AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroup`**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-security-group.html)

So it should look like this:

```yaml
Resources:
  ElasticacheSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      Description: "Access from webservers only"
  ElasticacheCluster:
    Type: "AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster"
    DependsOn: ElasticacheSecurityGroup
    Properties:
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: "true"
      Engine: "memcached"
      CacheNodeType: "cache.t1.micro"
      NumCacheNodes: "1"
      CacheSecurityGroupNames:
      - Ref: ElasticacheSecurityGroup
```